# Perform ngFor after function invokes it?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a lot of data to handle, so when the ngFor is used it is taking some time to render it. In normal Jquery way I used a loop and when more button is clicked it will render next 10 and used the .append(). Since I'm using angular I don't want the jQuery way. Suggest me another way if any exists.

Comment: Only push elements into the array you're refering in your ngFor when invoking your method. Keep it simple.

Comment: I need all the elements in the array, that's the problem

Comment: Are you trying to achieve pagination?

Comment: would using an infinite scroll or pagination component help?

Comment: It would help us if you update the question with what you're trying to do (visually). btw what's the array length ngFor is usually very fast.

Comment: You can just split your array into a private and rendered scope. 
_wholeArray: [];
renderedArray: [];

*ngFor="let el of renderedArray"

Comment: My requirement is that when the component loads initially it should render first 10 elements in div and if more button is clicked the ngFor should render the next 10 in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, actually one of the comments helped me. I had a big array and then i took only a part of it and rendered it when the component loaded. When the more button is clicked I pushed the next set of data into the rendered array. When the more button was clicked I just had to change the index values of from and to in the main array, so only a few set of data got pushed into rendered array. *ngFor is absolutely awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use **trackBy** as explained (https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

We can help Angular to track which items added or removed by providing a trackBy function. The trackBy function takes the index and the current item as arguments and needs to return the unique identifier for this item. Now when you change the collection, Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the things that changed.

```
<img *ngFor="let picture of pictures; trackBy: trackImageId" [src]="picture.path">

trackImageId(index: number, picture: PictureModel) {
        return picture.id;
}
```

Comment: My requirement is that when the component loads initially it should render first 10 elements in div and if more button is clicked the ngFor should render the next 10 in the loop

Comment: go for pagination and get the records in chunks of 10 \and display it

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list" let-i="index">
  <li class="dropdown-item" (click)="onClick(item)" *ngIf="i<11">{{item.text}}</li>
</ng-container
```

**closer to answer**
    {{item.text}}