# Why does my UI freeze until the API call is terminated?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-httpclient

I have an API call that downloads all Italian municipalities, which is nearly 8000.
The problem is that the page loads the HTML, but I can't click anything until the API call is over.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.loadComuni();
}
loadComuni(){
   //Italian municipalities
   this.RegisterService.getMunicipalities().subscribe(
      obj=>{
        this.city=obj;
      },
      error=>{
        console.log("error", error);
   });
}


<div class="col-12 col-lg-4"">
 <select id="cbComNasc" class="form-control" formControlName="cbComNasc">
      <option *ngFor="let c of city" [ngValue]="c.citta">{{c.citta}}</option>
 </select>
</div>



//getMunicipalities
  public getMunicipalities():Observable<Comuni[]>{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        'Accept':  'application/json'
      })
    }; 
    return this.HttpClient.get<Comuni[]>(environment.apiURL+"api/v1/gestionale/GetComuni",httpOptions)
  }
```

I also tried with the async pipe or with the promise but the problem is the same.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `getMunicipalities` under your `RegisterService`?

Comment: @codeitup I've update the question, so you can see the service call.

Comment: Umm, I dont see any issues in the service method also, not sure whats causing that, look for some other causes, since the Http calls are async in nature, so they will never block your UI.

Comment: @codeitup I see from F12-> Network that the call to api take 800ms for response; and the page is not free until the call ends.

Comment: use `ngOnInit` instead `ngAfterViewInit` method. maybe fixed!

Comment: @kian I change it but nothing it's change

Comment: changing the method wont help, since its not the cause

Comment: What do you mean by page is not free, also can you elaborate what do you mean by page freezing?...is it that content not loaded ? animation not playing / hanging? or something

Comment: @codeitup In my page there are multiple input box, including the select with api response information. The html page is load and the css is load( included some animation), so i can see the input fields with all css styles; but I can't click anything until the api call is not finished.

Comment: maybe its because the data in these fields are dependant on the api call and till the api resolves these options doesnt have anything to show?, but if its like nothing is interacting then its strange!

Comment: It may be because you're trying to render 8000+ options. Try `this.city = []` and see if that speeds things up.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825268/12371697). If you're having a large amount of data ngFor will take some time to render them, so have a separate array and render 10 to 20 records initially and if the user scroll to the bottom render 10 t0 more or have a pagination feature.

Comment: I didn't fix it exactly like that, but thanks for the idea it helped me